# Find first underlying primitive in struct/class

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

## Premise:

I have a variadic template function that accepts PODs (plain-old data structure) with homogeneous member types.

An acceptable POD may be composed entirely of 4-byte integers XOR 4-byte floats.

Internally, the variadic parameter is coerced to a pointer of the underlying type and utilized as a primitive array.

## Problem:

Currently, the template function requires the user to provide some additional information about the formatting of these PODs; such as in the following:

### Declaration

```
template<typename ...U>
void foo(const char *format, U... bars);
```

### Usage

```
Blah much, wow; // Underlying type is integral.
Bleh such, params; // underlying type is float.
//... 
foo("iffi",much,params,such,wow);
```

It works, but I would like to bypass the formatting string.

## Question:

Is there a way to evaluate the underlying type at compile-time?

*Edit:* The layout of the structure and the names of its members are not known until compile-time. That is, the **user of the library** is providing an arbitrary homogeneous POD.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]; how do those structs really look like? how many different types such as `Blah`, `Bleh` etc. are there?

Comment: The comments specify that the structures are POD with uniform/homogeneous underlying type. The problem specifies that the type is provided by a user and is therefore unknown by the library.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass string formatting, you may create a trait:

```
template <typename T /*, typename AlwaysVoidForSFINAE = void*/> struct UnderlyingPodType;

template <> struct UnderlyingPodType<Blah> { using type = int; };
template <> struct UnderlyingPodType<Bleh> { using type = float; };

template<typename ...Ts>
void foo(Ts&&... ts)
{
    using types = std::tuple<UnderlyingPodType<std::decay_t<Ts>>...>;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The layout of the structure and its member names are unknown.

Comment: @EsmeraldaSalamone: I rewrite an answer with that new information.

Comment: This requires defining template specializations for each type, which really defeats the purpose of what I'm going for.

I don't want the user of the function to have to provide such definitions for their type.